# ¿ Como recoger datos en un formulario con ASP .NET Webforms?

Tags: asp.net

Estoy haciendo un formulario ASP .NET Webforms

A la hora de hacer el diseño del formulario es mejor hacerlo solo con etiquetas HTML o se debe hacer mezclando las herramientas de objetos de ASP Webforms

Es decir para el formulario y los botones lo puedo hacer asi en HTML:

```
<form id="pasoForm" action = "respuesta.html" method = "post" >
<input type = "submit" name = "boton1" id = "boton1" class ="ir-btn" />
</form>
```

O usando los objetos Estándar de ASP

```
<form id="pasoForm" runat="server">
<asp:Button  runat="server" Text="boton1" ID="boton1"></asp:Button>
</form>


<form id="pasoForm" runat="server">
<button type="button" name="boton1" id="boton1" class="ir-btn" onclick="step1()">Continuar</button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar ambas maneras, si lo que quieres es recuperar los datos con la forma ASP los campos aparecerán como controles en el code behind, si lo que quieres es usar es html puedes usar en atributo runat="server" para que por el id te aparezca en en code behind tambien.

```
<input type = "submit" runat="server" name = "boton1" id = "boton1" class ="ir-btn" />
```

Mi opinión seria realizar esto con ajax, ya que con este método tendrás que refrescar la pantalla y no sera muy responsiva la aplicación.

Puedes ver como hacer esto en el siguiente [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331986/how-to-use-ajax-with-asp-net-webforms)

Comment: ¿ Puedo entonces usar la validación con html5 y con runat="server" ver los campos como controles en code behind ?

Comment: Así es, recuerda que el id de la etiqueta HTML sera el control que veras en el code behind. Aunque para usar las validaciones de HTML5 creo que deberías revisar el siguiente link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj129609.aspx ya que no me consta que las validaciones de HTML5 funcionen correctamente con WebForms.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda !